# How to map same folder to another domain name on Apache

Tags: apache, virtualhost, document-root

I have a website with some domain name like myexample.com. I want to add another name to my domain, like abc.myexample.com.

If a user accesses the site using either name, it should load with the same content. Using the server team's help I mapped the same ip to a new domain name. But now how do I root the myexample.com path to abc.myexample.com to show same content? How can I do through it cpanel or using putty?

Comment: What hosting platform are you using ? IIS, Apache ?

Comment: hosting platform which i used is apache (LAMP).